# How to extract HTML styled text from an EditText in Android?

Tags: android, html, android-edittext

I am using `HTML.fromHTML(...)` to style the text of an EditText in Android. I need to pass the styled text back as a result to another activity. However, when I use an intent to pass the contents of the EditText I am unable to figure out how to retain the HTML style of the original text.

As an example, suppose that the original text in the EditText is:

Today is the 21<sup>st</sup>

When I extract the text of using `edittext.getText()` and send it back as a result the resulting text is:

Today is the 21st

Is there a way to extract the HTML styled string from the EditText?

Comment: duh, of course :-) Please add your comment as an answer so I can mark the question as answered.

Comment: Just posted it as the answer. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can send the HTML text itself and then call Html.fromHTML in the activity to which you are passing this text. fromHTML is meant to be used for text which has to be displayed on the screen

Answer (score 16):

Use this to get the HTML of the styled text. You can use the HTML in EditText, TextView or WebView

```
String htmlString=Html.toHtml(edittext.getText());
```

Comment: +1 This solution also works except that the argument to `HTML.toHtml()` must be cast as `Spanned`.

Comment: You can directly use getText method of EditText without casting

Comment: I tried your solution and it works but Eclipse complained about casting. Hence, my comment.

Comment: Should be String htmlString = Html.toHtml((Spanned) edittext.getText());

Answer (score 4):

This won't work if your text is not spanned:

```
edittext.setText("");
//error here:
String htmlString = Html.toHtml((Spanned) edittext.getText());
```

You need to cast it by creating an instance first:

```
String htmlString = Html.toHtml(new SpannableString(edittext.getText()));
```